# Plant-human hybrid?

Tags: genetics, hybridization

I was bored on YouTube so I searched "plant-human hybrid" and this video came up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiZ35pkxG-k. and I want to know if this is actually possible, I checked the comments but they where mostly weed jokes, so is this possible

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. I would ask you to relieve your boredom by reading the guided tour and finding out what constitutes a suitable question. Questions should be comprehensible in themselves and not require one to follow a link to find them. You need to describe what was proposed in the film in your question. Otherwise it is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 4):

This is already a common phenomenon in biotechnology. Perhaps it is exactly not what you think or saw in the video. By the way, in the video the plant was *Mimosa pudica* and the phenomenon was seismonastic movement...so a very misleading video.

Biotechnology already harnesses plant-non plant hybrids to be specific to produce transgenic plants which uses the useful genes from a different organism to produce a particular vitamin, drug, enzymes, etc in large amount.This phenomenon is called molecular farming and such hybrid plants act as bioreactors.

Similarly mouse genome segments may be used to produce antibody producing plants through their fruits or seeds. *Brassica napus* uses segments of DNA from Hirudinea organisms like leech to mass produce hirudin used in medicinal product.

It is quite similar to *E. coli* in which segments of human genes are introduced to mass produce insulin.The *E. coli* serves as a bioreactor in this case.

I'm mentioning only a few references which explains the detailed processes by which the entire plant cell is endowed with the special traits from other organisms.

FOR REFERENCE:https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9274048E

https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v342/n6245/abs/342076a0.html

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetically_modified_crops